# How to read abc.txt.gz file in react js?

Tags: reactjs

- hi i am having problem to read a .gz file compressed by *php code:*
- i am using following function in php for compressing in .gz in php i am able to uncompress,

  > $compressed   = gzcompress('Compress me', 9);
- but I dont know if there is any way to read `.gz file in react
  js*`. I am new to this. ***Thanks in advance*.**

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://medium.com/@harrietty/zipping-and-unzipping-files-with-nodejs-375d2750c5e4) article:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');

const fileContents = fs.createReadStream('./abc.txt.gz');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./abc.txt');
const unzip = zlib.createGunzip();

fileContents.pipe(unzip).pipe(writeStream);
```

You have to install the [zlib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zlib) module.

This code is assuming that the file to be executed is located in the same directory as `abc.txt.gz`. It creates a file called `abc.txt` which is the unzipped version.

Comment: hi i am getting TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function

Answer (score 0):

use zlib for compress and decompress buffer,
fetch your compressed string by your php and call my unzipMe function
base of this function on base64 string, if you fetch except base64 then change unzipMe.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

var zlib = require("zlib");

function App() {
  const [decodeStr, setDecodeStr] = React.useState("");

  var utf8ArrayToStr = (function() {
    var charCache = new Array(128); // Preallocate the cache for the common single byte chars
    var charFromCodePt = String.fromCodePoint || String.fromCharCode;
    var result = [];

    return function(array) {
      var codePt, byte1;
      var buffLen = array.length;

      result.length = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < buffLen; ) {
        byte1 = array[i++];

        if (byte1 <= 0x7f) {
          codePt = byte1;
        } else if (byte1 <= 0xdf) {
          codePt = ((byte1 & 0x1f) << 6) | (array[i++] & 0x3f);
        } else if (byte1 <= 0xef) {
          codePt =
            ((byte1 & 0x0f) << 12) |
            ((array[i++] & 0x3f) << 6) |
            (array[i++] & 0x3f);
        } else if (String.fromCodePoint) {
          codePt =
            ((byte1 & 0x07) << 18) |
            ((array[i++] & 0x3f) << 12) |
            ((array[i++] & 0x3f) << 6) |
            (array[i++] & 0x3f);
        } else {
          codePt = 63; // Cannot convert four byte code points, so use "?" instead
          i += 3;
        }

        result.push(
          charCache[codePt] || (charCache[codePt] = charFromCodePt(codePt))
        );
      }

      return result.join("");
    };
  })();

  const unzipMe = base64gz => {
    // if your data not a base64 then comment this line
    let compressData = atob(base64gz);
    compressData = compressData.split("").map(function(e) {
      return e.charCodeAt(0);
    });

    let binData = new Uint8Array(compressData);

    zlib.gunzip(binData, function(err, dezipped) {
      const str = utf8ArrayToStr(dezipped);
      setDecodeStr(str);
    });
  };

  const gzStr = "H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJV3BKTErM1gEAVJXqUQwAAAA=";
  unzipMe(gzStr);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Coded string : {gzStr}</h1>
      <hr />
      <h2>Decoded string : {decodeStr}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I used this site for testing compress string : [Compress Str to gz](http://www.txtwizard.net/compression)

Answer output: [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-jepsen-21on5)